# curl exec return null only

Tags: php, curl

PHP code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    try {
            $ch = curl_init();

            if (FALSE === $ch)
                throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 

            $content = curl_exec($ch);

            if (FALSE === $content)
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));


            return $content;
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
                $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
                E_USER_ERROR);

        }
}
```

I call this function like this `var_dump(file_get_contents_curl("http://www.google.com"));die;`
But this return only null;
I run this code on other server with same config  and worked,

`allow_url_fopen` is  On

Alse `file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/')` return false to me????

I am very very very confused.please help me :(
[image]

Same Time from two server
[image]

And compare two PHP.ini
[image]

Comment: Do you have curl installed?

Comment: Does the other server have curl installed / enabled?

Comment: IN TWO SERVER CURL IS ENABLED

Comment: Maybe it just happens the site is down or inaccessible for server 2?

Comment: @Mihai the same time this code worked on server1 and not worked on server2?!

Comment: You might have firewall restrictions.

Comment: compare php settings on bot servers.

Comment: Execute the curl request on the console, to see if it works. Perhaps curl command isn't available because it's not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have firewall restrictions or you have not access to internet

Comment: I am stupid,yes server2 have not access to internet ;)